# Exporting and opening CSVs using .rmd file in R

Tags: r, export, r-markdown

I'm working on code in R that formats and creates data frames that I want to share using a .rmd file.  In my code, I use `write.csv` and `file.show` to create and open CSV files of the formatted datasets.  Since we are using .rmd to show the code I wrote for formatting, I was wondering if there's a way to also have `write.csv` and `file.show` run when someone opens the .rmd file?  I've looked around Google and RStudio to see if 1) this is even possible and 2) if it is possible, how to do it, but I haven't found anything.  So my question is, is an .rmd file even capable of exporting and opening files, and if so, how do I do it?

Comment: What operating system are you using? If you have a program you wish to open the files in, you could use a `system` call (or perhaps `shell.exec`, to open the `csv` in an external system. An `rmd` file is simply a literate programing document (text + code). `knitr` executes this code (`Rstudio` has a button that will run in a separate non-interactive session) and creates a document.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example. It turns out `file.show` does not work in an Rmd, which shouldn't be too surprising.

````
This is  atest
========================================================

Make some data

```{r}
df <- data.frame(a=rnorm(10), b=rnorm(10))
```

Write data

```{r}
write.csv(df, "df.csv", row.names=FALSE)
```

Show the data
You will find that this does not work

```{r}
#file.show(df)
#View(df)
```

but this does
```{r}
print(df) 
```
````