# fix r sum() auto remove the small digital .05

Tags: r, sum, digits

i have a problem that when I use R sum() function, the sum() automatically remove the small number e.g. 0.05 in the total.

any suggestions on how to fix this? 
originally I use dplyr summarize(sum()) function.and i find the problem

```
dfexl %>% 
  filter(Text=='Totalt') %>%
  summarise( number_of_total = n(),
             grundbook_total = sum(Konto, na.rm = T))
```

and the simplest version is

```
sum(22068.00, 144501.00,  71153.00,  26193.05,  10395.00 , 80619.00)
```

it will output:  354929
rather than  354929.05

any suggestion?

i even use the following 2 methords, not able to fix

```
dfexl %>% 
  filter(Text=='Totalt') %>%
  summarise( number_of_total = n(),
             grundbook_total = round(sum(Konto * 100, na.rm = T)/100,4))
```

if I use grundbook_total*100 then I can see 35492905.

```
options(digits=4)
```

Thank you!

Comment: Try: `options(digits=10)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this is just a printout issue; if you want to increase the number of significant digits in the printout, you could try:

```
sprintf("%.2f",sum(22068.00, 144501.00,  71153.00,  26193.05,  10395.00 , 80619.00))
# [1] "354929.05"
```

And to change the number of digits, just change the number in the first argument, i.e.:

```
sprintf("%.10f",sum(22068.00, 144501.00,  71153.00,  26193.05,  10395.00 , 80619.00))
#[1] "354929.0500000000"
```

Comment: Thank you so much, but if 1. i need to output this as .csv file or excel file rather than print2. I am using R markdown, I hope I can check the result in the markdown place, how should I do those?  thank you so much!!

Comment: R will store the data in its full form - if you save it as an CSV it should show the full value `example <- sum(22068.00, 144501.00,  71153.00,  26193.05,  10395.00 , 80619.00); write.csv(example,"~Filepath/SO_example.csv",row.names=FALSE)` When I write it to a CSV it saves the full value

Comment: I'm not too familiar with the nuances of Rmarkdown, so dont want to tell you wrong - but this may be of help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18363757/exporting-and-opening-csvs-using-rmd-file-in-r